# generate text alert from WIndows Laptop or any sort of alert

Tags: windows, alert

How can I let a java code run every few mins on my laptop Windows Professional and then if a certain condition happens - send a text alert to me on my phone? Or any other sort of notification?

I am monitoring a lengthy automated process. I have the code ready that monitors a status table to check some values. Certain scenarios - I need to be notified 24X7.

What is the best way to achieve this?